# Hermitian operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the space of differentiable complex-valued functions on the unit circle in the complex plane, and for $f,g \in V$, define $$\langle f,g \rangle= \int_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(\theta)}g(\theta)\,d\theta. $$ (a) Show that this form is Hermitian and positive definite.

$$
\begin{align}
& \langle f,g \rangle= \int_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(\theta)}g(\theta)\,d\theta\\ 
& = \int_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(\theta)\overline{g(\theta)}}\,d\theta\\
& = \overline{\int_0^{2\pi} \overline{g(\theta)}f(\theta)\,d\theta}\\
& = \overline{\langle g,f \rangle}
\end{align}
$$

Let $f(\theta)=f_1(\theta)+if_2(\theta)$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are real valued functions. Then: $$\langle f,f \rangle= \int_0^{2\pi}[f_1(\theta)]^2\,d\theta+\int_0^{2\pi}[f_2(\theta)]^2\,d\theta>0$$ b) Let $W$ be the subspace of $V$ of functions $f(e^{i\theta})$, where $f$ is polynomial of degree $\leq n$. Find an orthonormal basis for $W$.

$\cal{B}= \{\frac{e^{i k\theta}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\}_{k=\{0,\dots,n\}}$ is an orthonormal basis.

c) Show that $T=i\frac{d}{d\theta}$ is a Hermitian operator on $V$, and determine its eignevalues on $W$.

Could someone help me please with the last question?

Comment: note that $\mathcal B = \{ \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ik\theta} \}_{k=0}^n$

Comment: @AlexR Ah ! Sorry..

Comment: No problem :) This should make finding eigenvectors easier.

Comment: @AlexR Not really.. :) Could you show me how to show it is Hermitian first ?

Comment: So you want to show $\langle Tf, g\rangle = \overline{\langle f, Tg\rangle}$, correct?

Comment: Well before I was told I have to show that it is an Hermitian "form". And now Hermitian "operator". Is it the same thing ?

Comment: According to [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianOperator.html), yes.

Comment: Could you perhaps write me a full answer. Because I have many similar problems, and I would like a basis problem. If you don't mind of course. But I could use it a lot please

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
\langle Tf, g \rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} \overline{i \frac d{d\theta} f(\theta)} g(\theta) d\theta & = - i \int_0^{2\pi} \overline{\frac d{d\theta} f(\theta)} g(\theta) d\theta \\
& = \underbrace{- i \left[ \overline{f(\theta)} g(\theta) \right]_0^{2\pi}}_{=0} +\int_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(\theta)} i \frac d{d\theta} g(\theta) d\theta \\
& = \langle f, Tg \rangle
\end{align*}$$
I seem to have a mistake in the partial integration part, but I don't find it right now, so here's what I got ad hoc.

Comment: Thank you but could you include the eigenvalues as well for the same reason as above ? I would highly appreciate it

Comment: @user91657 First I'd like to figure out the (probably dumb) mistake.
For the eivenvectors use $\mathcal B$ and see what $T \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ik\theta}$ is.

Comment: Why do you keep the bar after having calculated the conjugate ? Between the first and second expression ?

Comment: $\overline{zw} = \bar{z} \cdot \bar{w}$ is the corresponding identity

Comment: I don't know what is wrong. Perhaps you should ask in Chat ? I can't because I am new to stack exchange